# Spout cannot handle the excel file that weighs 8 megabytes. Why?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I do as in the [documentation](https://opensource.box.com/spout/getting-started/).

```
    logger()->info('start');

    $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
    $reader->open($filePath);

    foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            echo 1;
        }
    }

    logger()->info('stop');
```

**Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded", "exception":**

Usually, after this error, the php script continues to work on the server, but not now.

And php does not reach the "stop" log even after a few minutes.

Comment: Well, you can try increasing the max execution time: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the file contents may take some time, so nothing gets echoed in the first 30s, resulting in PHP killing the process. This can explain why you don't see the last log.

You can try increasing the max execution time to see if that helps: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php.